# Which model to choose for blackberry application development?

Tags: blackberry, model

I'm new in blackberry development and I want to know if there is some specific models that are best for testing applications before to buy one. I search on the Internet but I don't find anything about this, are all models the same for testing?

I know that for Android some functionalities not work in all smartphone models, is it the same for blackberry?

Moreover, can I test an application in testing phase in any blackberry or are they some specific characteristics that he must have?

PS: I developed in OS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me there is 2 point for making decision:

### 1. Simulators

- usually I run and debug my application on different emulators. My favorite simulator is BlackBerry Simulator_7.0.0.592_9790, it start faster than other that I try;
- using simulator you can try to run application on different devices, in my practice it's important, because sometimes there is really differences in execution especially between OS 6 and OS 7;
- but to run simulators comfortable you need powerful computer;
- BlackBerry simulators can provide different feature for simulation (rotation, usb cable connection, 3G network and other) that's why it suits for most application that are developing nowadays;
- for beginning it's really enough, I propose to start with simulator and if you faced with issue that simulator really can't provide to you than think about a real phone;
- and one trick that if you plan to develop for mostly for yourself and small project simulator is enough, as for small and big commercial project usually costumer provide devices for test.

### 2. Real devices

- choose more powerful device because it's more faster;
- running application in a real device you need to have keys to sign an application through BlackBerry server always when you try to run and debug it;
- I would prefer devices with touch screen, it's easy to navigate;
- other features not so important for me.
- now I use BlackBerry 9800 (Platform 6.0 with), it's quite comfortable to work with this device, but some issue that I noticed are bad WiFi connection when signal is weak, and lack lower performance if compare with it with BlackBerry Bold 9900 (Platform 7.0) but no touch screen there.  -

Answer (score 0):

You need to think if you need certain capabilities that vary from one model to another, such as:

- Whether or not you need a GPS enabled device.
- Connectivity: 3G? GPRS?
- Camera: autofocus?
- Touchscreen or trackpad (or both?)
- Screen dimensions (portrait, landscape)

Yo could also ask the client which BB models are more common in their organisation. Or if you are developing a product, try to find some stats on which are the most sold models in a market.

In general you'll need to test in as many real devices as you can, and don't rely on how the app behaves on simulators.